# Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I should first mention that I'm using SqlAlchemy through Flask-SqlAlchemy. I don't believe this affects the issue but if it does, please let me know.

Here is the relevant part of the error message I'm getting when running the create_all function in SqlAlchemy

`InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type. u'INSERT INTO podcasts (feed_url, title, url, last_updated, feed_data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (u'http://example.com/feed', u'Podcast Show Title', u'http://example.com', '2012-04-17 20:28:49.117000'`

Here is my model:

```
class Podcast(db.Model):
    import datetime
    __tablename__ = 'podcasts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feed_url = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    url = db.Column(db.String(150))
    last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    feed_data = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, feed_url):
        import feedparser

        self.feed_url = feed_url
        self.feed_data = feedparser.parse(self.feed_url)
        self.title = self.feed_data['feed']['title']
        self.url = self.feed_data['feed']['link']
```

Can someone tell me how I can get this to work? I've also tried the following model but that also doesn't work. Same error.

```
class Podcast(db.Model):
    import datetime
    __tablename__ = 'podcasts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feed_url = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    url = db.Column(db.String(150))
    last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    feed_data = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, feed_url):
        import feedparser

        self.feed_url = feed_url
        self.feed_data = feedparser.parse(self.feed_url)
        self.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.title = self.feed_data['feed']['title']
        self.url = self.feed_data['feed']['link']
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `last_updated` column is the problem? Could it be the `feed_data` column (which is column 4 if you start counting from zero)? After all, you're trying to put a dictionary (the result of `feedparser.parse(...)` into a column of Text type.

Comment: I think you should be using sqlalchemy.func.now() instead of datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: `last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)` is the **correct** way to specify that the last updated time = now.  Doing `default=datetime.datetime.now())` is **wrong** because the timestamp will be fixed at compile time.  See the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions).  At the time of writing, _all_ the answers to this question are **wrong** (and don't address the original issue).

Answer (score 21):

Try to use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`. This works for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Set the import out the class.

```
from datetime import datetime

last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
```

or

```
import datetime

last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I did this

Answer (score -9):

Look at your line:

```
last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

There is no `datetime.datetime.now` attribute in python. However, there **is** a `datetime.datetime.now()` **function** in python. You were just missing a pair of parentheses.

Comment: No, sqlalchemy requires a callable.  If you add the parentheses, you get a constant value for all entries.

Comment: @adamek `something.myfunc` returns the function itself, without calling it; this is desired behavior. If you called the function, you'd be retrieving only a single time and using that as the default, which is a different behavior and not desired.