# How to insert datetime using sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have this code to insert into SQLITE some rows, using alchemy :

```
 df['date_create'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_create'])

 list1 = df.to_dict(orient='records') 
 list1= list1[0]
 metadata = sql.schema.MetaData(bind=dbengine,reflect=True)
 table = sql.Table(table1, metadata, autoload=True)

 Session = sql.orm.session.sessionmaker(bind=dbengine)
 session = Session()
 res= dbengine.execute(table.insert(), list1)
```

But, I got this error message:

```
(exceptions.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts 
Python datetime and date objects as input.
```

How to pass datetime for insertion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201648/sqlalchemy-wont-accept-datetime-datetime-now-value-in-a-datetime-column

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Pandas defines a lot of its own types so the Pandas `to_datetime` method returns one of its internal datetime types and not a "real" Python datetime. SQLite wouldn't know how to work with the Pandas datetime. Try converting those Pandas datetimes to Python datetimes before trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite does not have explicit storage support for date or datetime objects. Instead it stores date (or datetime)objects as Text, Real, or Integer. See [Sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for details.